# ember-model example application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model, data-layer

I'm looking for an example application using ember-model (https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model)

I'm looking for an example that:

- Showcases both object fetching and creation,
- Showcases writing of a custom adapter,
- Has complete sources available

I read through the ember-model docs on GitHub, I've seen an Ember-cast on the subject (http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/getting-started-with-ember-model).

**CAVEAT**: Not to be confused with EmberData, a competing solution. Ember-model is an independently developed alternative.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I do not think these resources are easy to find. I searched through the web for a couple hours and didn't find anything satisfactory. Perhaps someone with a little bit more experience could share some resources. I would think this would be useful for others as well.

Comment: Questions are suppose to be for asking specific questions with technical answers, not just asking for examples.  There's plenty of examples in the Ember Guides.  Try what you're attempt to accomplish and post here if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: @NicholasJohn16: Ember-model is an independent library (see the GitHub link), thus there will be no information available on Ember.js official page. To the contrary, it covers EmberData that is a competing solution. I would ask a specific technical question if I had one, however in this case I simply don't have a good starting point and the documentation is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a presentation on it at an Ember meetup once, here's the doc

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1syDpGOveVxk01qyFCXtiVruIUNBk0IK6_K5PQee76eE/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000

I use it in one of my enterprise apps, and Ember Data in another, Ember Data is better IMHO.  Ember Data is also supported by a larger conglomerate of people, and is updating more frequently.

Comment: I chose Ember.Model over Ember.Data primarily because I almost certainly will need to heavily extend it (certain performance considerations). Ember.Data - although more feature rich seems to be also more rigid and much more complicated. Extending Ember.Model seems feasible, extending Ember.Data - not really.